# Registering multiple file types which an iOS app can support

Tags: ios, regex

My app needs to open files from email, but the problem is that the files usually comes with the numeric file extension file.001 file.002 file.123 etc.

I'm referring to this apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html)

Do I have to list all items from 000 to 999 manually? 
or can I use regex or some other trick to make it simple?

Comment: Well, you can match file names with RegEx for sure like `\.[0-9]{3}$`.

Comment: to open it with your app - you NEED to set up your Info.plist to let the OS know that you can handle file.000, file.001 (register your app as able to handle certain UTIs) - so... you must "list" all items